# JAVA running too much time

Tags: java, biginteger

This is my code,it has been one hour but it hasn't returned a value yet,is there anything wrong?

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class PROJECTV1 {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {    
        BigInteger bResult = bigFunctionExample_2();
            System.out.println(" => result_got:" + bResult);    
        System.out.println(); //newline     
    }// end_main

    public static BigInteger bigFunctionExample_2() {    
        BigInteger bSum = BigInteger.ZERO;
        BigInteger bTmp;
        String sSum;
        // BigInteger bResult =0;

        for (int i = 1; ; i++) {    
            bTmp = BigInteger.valueOf(i);    
            bTmp = bTmp.pow(2); // i^2    
            bSum = bSum.add(bTmp); // sum = i^2+ (i-1)^2 + ....

            sSum = bSum.toString();    
            if (sSum.length() > 30) {

                System.out.println("i=" + i + " bSum =" + bSum);    
                break;
            }

        }//end_for

        return bSum; // result
    }
    // end_bigFunctionExample_2    
}
```

Comment: Your code is *really* hard to read at the moment, with the random blank lines and the lack of indentation. Please take more time when you post - make the post look like the kind of post *you'd* want to answer.

Comment: @FredLarson: When it hits the `break` statement, presumably...

Comment: @FredLarson At the break statement.  Granted, that's really poor style for a loop... It should probably be a `while` loop instead.

Comment: I should have looked for that. <blush>

Comment: Try to print whole values first. Use `System.out.print()` before if statement you'll at least come to know what values are being calculated.

Comment: `bSum = bSum.add(bTmp); // sum = i^2+ (i-1)^2 + ....` Not really.

Comment: "is there anything wrong" - well we don't know what the code is meant to do, so we can't tell.

Comment: @SujanSivagurunathan: Um, I really think it is. Because the previous value of `bSum` will be `(i-1)^2 + ... + 1^2`, and we're adding `i^2`.

Comment: Do you reall expect the sum to be 30 digits long? I think you need to go 1 through MAXINT millions of times to get there.

Comment: @Jon Skeet , I would have wrote sum = i^2+ (i+1)^2 +...+(i+n)^2. Never mind, I guess it depends on how you see and how you read it. Since there is only incrementation of i, I guess the minus in the equation shocked me.

Comment: instead of constantly calculating powers of 2 you can just keep a running sum of odd numbers to determine the next power of 2...1, 1 + 3 = 4, 4 + 5 = 9, 9 + 7 = 16...its an interesting property you can take advantage of

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that loop to break, it must reach `10^30 ~= 2^100`. Sum of the squares of the first `n` natural numbers is approximately equal to `n^3`. So your loop will break approximately when `i` becomes `10^10 ~= 2^33`. I guess `int i` is 32-bit so you <s>MIGHT be</s> are overflowing that integer, I didn't do the exact math but it's very possible.

If you go for a 64-bit variable (`long`?), which has an upper limit of approximately `10^19`, <s>you might have a chance</s> it will be OK.

Edit: Here's the exact math from [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+of+i%5E2+from+i%3D1+to+x+%3D+10%5E30).

Comment: Thanks for your help,I think I should work it all over again.

Comment: Can you explain the "might have a chance" ?

Comment: Did you mean "Sum of squares of first n natural numbers" ?

Comment: According to WolframAlpha, `i` is going to be `~1.4 * 10^10` when the sum hits `10^30` so `long i` is enough to prevent overflow.